# Running club convegence approach with unbalanced panel data in stata

Tags: stata, convergence

Hello Community Members,

I have data for Indian manufacturing industries from year 2000 to 2020. This data has been categorized as per manufacturing activities and across states.
Problem: Suppose I am checking for the club convergence for Iron and steel industry across Indian states for the given years. For some states production activity is there for all years, but not the same for rest of the states. Due to this my panel is unbalanced. Now when I am running the Philip and Sul Club convergence approach in Stata, it is showing error in the code that it can't run on unbalanced panel, first make it strongly balanced.

Please, help me with the possibility of running this model with unbalanced panel.

Regards,
Vikas.

Tried: I have tried running the model, but getting errors due to the unbalanced panel data. Once I make it balanced by dropping all the states where data is not available for all the years, my codes are running fine.

Expecting: I don't want to drop any observations,  want to run the same model on unbalanced panel.